# Python Formatter Tool

Tags: python, formatter

I was wondering if there exists a sort of Python beautifier like the gnu-indent command line tool for C code. Of course indentation is not the point in Python since it is programmer's responsibility but I wish to get my code written in a perfectly homogenous way, taking care particularly of having always identical blank space between operands or after and before separators and between blocks.

Comment: See also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242748/programmatic-python-source-formatter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatic python source formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242748/programmatic-python-source-formatter)

Answer (score 15):

I am the one who asks the question. In fact, the tool the closest to my needs seems to be [PythonTidy](http://www.lacusveris.com/PythonTidy/) (it's a Python program of course : Python is best served by himself ;) ).

Comment: Thanks, I'm using PythonTidy now thanks to this, and it's proving useful. It uses the proper mechanism - i.e. the compiler.ast module to parse source into an AST, then walks the AST nodes getting them to write themselves out according to user-defined rules. The code is also very clear, so understanding and modifying its workings to suit my particular standards did not present much difficulty. Though I guess you'd expect clear code from someone who cares deeply enough about formatting to write an automated tool! 10/10

Answer (score 3):

autopep8 attempts to automate making your code conform to pep8 coding standards

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8

Answer (score 3):

You can also try `yapf`:

> A formatter for Python files

https://github.com/google/yapf/

Answer (score 1):

[PyLint](http://freshmeat.net/projects/pylint/) has some formatting checks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [pindent](http://www.koders.com/python/fid66946EDA1E4704E4DE82C3385E16309B10C0C683.aspx?s=md5)?

Comment: The link seems broken.

Answer (score 1):

[`black`](https://github.com/psf/black) is another recent option.

It provides deliberate and fast code formatting and is used by many projects such as `pytest`, `SQLAlchemy` and `Pillow` to name a few.