# Programmatic python source formatter

Tags: python

I have a large body of python code that needs to have a pep8-compliant style/format imposed on it. There are variants of pep8 that various rules (like [this one by a coworker](https://github.com/wgen/pep8)), but the hardest thing is to deal with splitting too long lines and formatting the modified code.

I've looked up the questions on this:

1. [python-formatter-tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032393/python-formatter-tool)
2. [python-source-formatter-pretty-printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913324/python-source-formatter-pretty-printer)

They are from 2009 and 2010. I am hoping that better tools have been developed since then.

I know about PythonTidy which is pretty good but makes lots of code worse, IMHO. Pylint detects formatting errors but does not correct them. Web services are not really relevant to my requirements because I want a tool that can be part of a build.

Does anyone have a recommendation that has not already been covered? Thanks.

Comment: And it is not programmatic, presumably.

Comment: As for the vote-to-close, it would be helpful to know why the two previous questions on python formatting tools have no close votes but this attempt does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's [yapf](https://github.com/google/yapf) works very well.

There's an online demo here: [yapf.now.sh](https://yapf.now.sh/)

You can integrate it into your workflow and run it when you save files in your editor or as a git precommit hook or something like that.

Comment: Stop the clock. We have a winner. This is the closest thing to what I want. And it took only six years to get the answer!

Answer (score 7):

Another one that looks pretty decent: [autopep8](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8)

But note that blindly following all the conventions in PEP8 isn't really in the spirit of PEP8. From PEP8 itself:

> But most importantly: know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes the
>   style guide just doesn't apply.

Comment: I should have commented earlier that I have something that deals with some pep8 errors but nothing that intelligently handles lines that are too long, leading me to believe that a more general solution, a code formatter, is required.

Answer (score 3):

[`black`](https://github.com/ambv/black) is another contender. It's selling point is that is is barely configurable, so your team wastes less time quibbling about details.

There's an online demo here: [black.now.sh](https://black.now.sh/?state=_Td6WFoAAATm1rRGAgAhARYAAAB0L-Wj4AQjAlldAD2IimZxl1N_WlkPinBFoXIfdFTaTVkGVeHShArYj9yPlDvwBA7LhGo8BvRQqDilPtgsfdKl-ha7EFp0Ma6lY_06IceKiVsJ3BpoICJM9wU1VJLD7l3qd5xTmo78LqThf9uibGWcWCD2JvcwWWdZBIVG-EZHQCfF_-sljga8I20AhGTTycGXViiSBUKK3nkZC4MoZ_G3xAhm8wwkY83Hom4UYxjW87XVeScHDUN156FRIyX83Zvl8oJx3ymXOy-jrB2L94755-kV351Z7SGF1yZahRWo8Hrnn4J_a18lro0ShL8cOxs6aA1USgGveTQiuaVx8_0XthmwVOYOKmGbSOIJLFNY68l89AWhPoBERUhjibdjj-T8rP03TYUfkNaY0m2qRBYRqhgiXezX8PmMmiAHLnmt__Vn7_rwXMWrsZ7U8WngUNkjvSgc6aM_JtXugrGuohdPN7vS93mC_Wo7TBCLJzdtxBFwkzEDzKEZwyk1pGDSLzFQ6kAJrQlBt0mXOzeVeOuw5K2I6cQdnPDwg6EUpc9T039L-fbRwTqDwprq_FYtHQyL8Z2B-HreV-GA9ijnSkxm6fWW4RR3v4KfXR0NkW6GqZ4R6j2WA84pn9fRnmdkmq9xqk1qMQLe82aZlKowIKxyJpvaVtrWctI765jAuP7LSXi6AQ4h952er6svgA9UD_WLU9NF__nCK5nrlxhrzcga06uzmDD7CsuCaXAHm45gOGQ45KKlGm1Wcrdr6WDa6hDtZ68IjScmUQW-eBGeo2EDv1R09TwVILB4EBjkxucWKsh09sAAAAAAkQHanVjl9q8AAfUEpAgAAF0lkL-xxGf7AgAAAAAEWVo%3D)

Side-note: `black`, `yapf`, and `autopep8` have python language server plugins, so they integrate nicely with text editors including atom and vscode.

Answer (score 2):

[PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) has this functionality built in and now has a free, open source community edition. Open your file up in it and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>.

Unifortunately, it will not also automatically refactor function names and variable names to PEP8 convention... those will have to be done one by one with PyCharm's rename functionality.

Answer (score 1):

PythonTidy seems to be splitting lines quite well http://www.lacusveris.com/PythonTidy/